# Writing to access database in Java?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a database project about adding, editing and deleting registries to a Students table which has fields:

Last_names, Names, IcNumber, Average, Entry_mode, Career and Change

In the editing frame i have a field where user types the icnumber of the student to edit its data, asks for the new data and saves it to a "Students" data structure, and then reupdates the registry with the new data:

```
String stmnt = "Insert Into Students (Last_names, Names, IcNumber, Average, " + 
        "Entry_mode, Career, Change) Values ('" + student.getLastNames() + 
        "', '" + student.getNames() + "', '" + student.getIcNumber() + "', " +
        student.getAverage() + ", '" + student.getEntry() + "', '" +
        student.getCareer() + "', '" + student.getChange() + "') " +
        "Where IcNumber = '" + field.getText() + "'";

statement.execute(stmnt);
```

And i get this Error message:

[Microsoft][Microsoft Access ODBC Driver] "Query input must contain at least one table or query."

I have tried a similar SQL Instruction in the adding registry area of my program without the "Where" condition and works good, anyone knows about that error?

Comment: Try SELECT on that table, then INSERT in a simple SQL string.

Comment: And, btw, use params instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Just as a side comment, use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), also make sure that the `Students` table exist and should you have a `where` statement on an `Insert`??

Comment: Why do you have a where clause in the insert statement?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried the same when adding a new registry but without the `where` because it just adds a registry without conditions, i this case i need that `where` because its gonna insert that data in the registry that matches the icNumber the user inputs its like `INSERT Into Students (Names) Values (newNames) Where IcNumber = 'inputIcNumber'`

Comment: @JorgeChayan The problem I see is it makes no sense to have a `where` on an `insert` statement because no data exists for the `where` to match to. If you want to update an existing record use `update`

Comment: Ok, thank you. it was a syntax mistake, i just let myself go by the sentence logic: Insert this data Where ic matches 'x' value, i'll try update and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `where` in a `insert` statement? `Where` clause is applicable in `select`, `update` and `delete` statements but not in `insert`. Also I don't see any need of the `where` clause in your query.

Simply use the `insert` statement without `where` clause.

Comment: I need the where because it's going to update a specific registry that matches the input icNumber, i'ma try update. Thanks!

Comment: Then use `update` statement e.g. `update Students  set Last_names = student.getLastNames(), ...... where IcNumber = field.getText()`.   Where you use `where`, it mean that record is already present in the table and if record is already present, `insert` doesn't make any sense. If still you have any doubts, please share your requirement with one data example. That will help understand better.

Comment: Yeah i just understood what everyone were trying to say, it was a syntax mistake, sorry for my ignorance and thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a subquery, first the SELECT part with WHERE and then the INSERT part
Something like:

```
  if (cond){
             (SELECT.....)
                (INSERT INTO...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statement to add a new record.  A `WHERE` clause does not belong in an `INSERT` statement.

If you're editing an existing record, then you should use an [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221186%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statement, and a `WHERE` clause makes sense to identify which record to change.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try this. I have used Insert With Where in other method and worked, but it was for a multi-valued field (access):


`statement.execute("Insert Into Students (Teachers.Value) Values ('"
                   + student.getIcNumber() + "') Where IcNumber = 
                   '" + professor.getIcNumber() + "';");`

Comment: Multi-valued fields are odd.  Each field "value" is like a separate recordset, and its member values must be referenced differently in SQL than with normal fields.  I wouldn't recommend anyone use multi-valued fields.  :-(

Comment: Believe me when i say that it was the only option i had for the requirements, apart of those fields, the last fields (Professors) is a field that depends on some values located in other table, this field reffers to the professors who make a solicitude for that specific student, so there can be various values on that field for each student, values which are the professors IcNumbers, which ones are located in the "Professors Table". I do the same for the Professors table, it has a Students field that depends on the students table, i have a double relationship in the tables.

Comment: And as the values can be 1, 2 or 1000 icnumbers located in another table, i used a multi-valued field